# .class vs .java

Tags: java, class, applet

What's the difference between a .class file and a .java file? I am trying to get my applet to work but currently I can only run it in Eclipse, I can't yet embed in HTML.
Thanks

**Edit: How to compile with JVM then?

Comment: regarding your edit... the JDK comes with a compiler called javac.

Comment: okay so then run in terminal: javac myFile.java

Comment: @Devoted: Yes. If it's a standalone app, you could then run: java myFile (or whatever you named the class, but it should be myFile).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A .class file is a compiled .java file.

.java is all text and is human readable.
.class is binary (usually).

You compile a java file into a class file by going to the command line, navigating to the .java file, and running

```
javac "c:\the\path\to\your\file\yourFileName.java"
```

You must have a java SDK installed on your computer (get it from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)), and make sure the javac.exe file is locatable in your computer's PATH environment variable.

Also, check out Java's **[Lesson 1: Compiling & Running a Simple Program](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava1/compile.html)**

If any of this is unclear, please comment on this response and I can help out :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say `.class` files are usually binary? When are they not?

Answer (score 32):

- .class -> compiled (for JVM)
- .java  -> source (for humans)

Answer (score 6):

A .java file contains your Java source code while a .class file contains the Java bytecode produced by the Java compiler. It is your .class files that run on the JVM to execute a Java application.

It is the .class files you will use when you deploy your applet.

Answer (score 4):

.java files are source files, while .class files are compiled (bytecode) classes.

Use [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) to compile source into bytecode.

Comment: dfa beat me to the punch by 22 seconds. ;)

Answer (score 3):

.java usually holds your code in clear text

.class contains the byte code of your .java. Think of it as a compiled version of the .java file

Answer (score 1):

person can be defined as a class Person. This class
should reside in a Java source code file (Person.java). Using this Java source code file,
the Java compiler (javac.exe on Windows or javac on Mac OS X/Linux/UNIX) generates
bytecode (compiled code for the Java Virtual Machine) and stores it in Person.class.

Answer (score 1):

Java files is an human readable language (for example, the code we write in Eclipse/any other IDE).

Class files are in byte-code compiled for Java Virtual Machine (JVM).